# Loading remote image into Tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am working on fetching an image from service into a table view cell. I have the image URL and i can fetch the image at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or in the  `layoutSubViews` method of table view cell. Which is the most efficient place to fetch remote data

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! MovieViewCell
    cell.title =  searchResultMovies[indexPath.row].title
    cell.movieImage = searchResultMovies[indexPath.row].poster
    return cell
}
```

The `layoutSubViews` method

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let title = self.title{
        titleLabel.text = title
    }
    if let movieImage = self.movieImage {
        movieImageView.loadImageFromString(imageString: movieImage)
    }
}
```

if you notice the above code you can see i am calling `loadImageFromString` from inside `layoutsubviews` which could also be done at  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` . Which is the better place to do it and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what the apple docs has to say about layoutSubviews:

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
>   layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the
>   autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not
>   offer the behavior you want.

Since loading an image has nothing to do with autoresizing or adjusting constraints, you'd be misusing the method. Additionally, layoutSubviews is often times called more than once for a visible view (such as when you rotate the device). You don't need to load the image more than once.

cellForRowAt is the appropriate method for downloading the image you need to configure the cell.

Answer (score 2):

There is no comparison between the 2 but the best practise is to make a config method inside the custom cell class and call it with the model to be set , `layoutSubviews` is meant for usage when you need to do something that depend on bounds of the view , BTW also make sure that `loadImageFromString` make use of a cache like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: Where do we call the config method inside the custom cell class from?  cellForRowAt?